# How to pretty-print json with long array in the same line

Tags: python, json

I want to store collected data in json, they are all arrays of integers with couple of thousand elements each.

I want the file to have the elements in the same list to be in the same line, should look like

```
{
    "foo": [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ],
    "bar": [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]
}
```

Right now, all I can find `json` in python can only be export with either

```
{'foo': [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ... , 'bar': [0 ...]}
```

Or

```
{
    "foo": [
        [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
        ],
        [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
```

But neither is desirable.

Comment: you could try the pprint package, it has more configuration options

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [`jsbeautifier`](https://pypi.org/project/jsbeautifier/):

```
import json
import jsbeautifier

x = {'foo': [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], 'bar': [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]}  


options = jsbeautifier.default_options()
options.indent_size = 2
print(jsbeautifier.beautify(json.dumps(x), options))
```

OUTPUT:

```
{
  "foo": [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  ],
  "bar": [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  ]
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want. But you answer so fast StackOverflow doesn't allow me to accept the answer before 14 minutes rofl

Comment: Glad it helped! ^^